# Three.js Object Grid

Tags: graphics, three.js

I want to draw a Grid with Three.js such that, given an object center and size:

1. It dynamically adjusts the granularity (space between grid lines) in relation the object size
2. The grid lines are not relative to the object

I've implemented the first requirement. The second is hard to explain, but its probably easier to understand with the example: https://jsfiddle.net/rendoir/gua7qd0s

In this demo, you can see that if you press 's', the size of the object increases and so does the grid. The grid divisions change accordingly to the order of magnitude of the object size.

The problem 2) is that the position of the grid is relative to the position of the object (they have the same center). Therefore, the grid always perfectly matches the object.
What I'm trying to do is to break this illusion, making it look like the grid exists in world-space, starting in the world origin and appearing behind the object.
The naive aproach would be to develop a grid with a size that could encompass the object starting at the origin. However, since the scene and the camera will be static (not the case in the example), I want a grid that is just enough to accomodate the object (doesn't need to start at the origin because the object may be far from it), and with the number of divisions (granularity between grid lines) still changing with its size.

I understand that the current solution for the fist problem may conflict with the second problem, so I'm looking for ideas or even existing solutions if there are any.

Note: You can assume the object is always a quad. By clicking 'c' you can also change the center of the object.

The main code is in the `Grid` class:

```js
let divisions = getDivisions(size);

let step = size / divisions;
let halfSize = size / 2;

let vertices = [];

for ( let i = 0, k = - halfSize + step; i < divisions - 1; i ++, k += step ) {

    vertices.push( - halfSize, k, 0, halfSize, k, 0 );
    vertices.push( k, - halfSize, 0, k, halfSize, 0 );

}
// ...
lineSegments.position.set(this.center.x, this.center.y, this.center.z);
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to do:

```
let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( theObject );

let sz = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3())

let root = new THREE.Object3D();
let maxSz = Math.max(Math.max(sz.x,sz.y),sz.z)
root.scale.multiplyScalar( 1.0 / maxSz )

root.add( theObject )
scene.add(root);
```

Now your object will always be scaled so that its maximum axis size is 1.

the Box3().setFromObject is really useful but it can have some cost depending on how much work THREE has to do to determine the resulting size of the object. So maybe avoid calling it constantly. object.localToWorld and .worldToLocal are also very useful.. just fyi.

Also fyi.. http://madebyevan.com/shaders/grid/ has some cool approaches to making grid shaders.

Comment: Your solution is very clever, however I'm having trouble replicating it in my (big-ish) codebase, but that's my problem! Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use shaders for that purpose.

Related forum topics:

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-infinitegridhelper-anti-aliased/8377?u=prisoner849

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-achieve-this-material-effect-gif-image/1270?u=prisoner849

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0x888888);
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var geom = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry();
var mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: `
    varying vec4 vPos;
    void main() {
        vPos = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * vPos;
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    //http://madebyevan.com/shaders/grid/
    
    #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable

    varying vec4 vPos;

    void main() {
      vec2 coord = vPos.xy;

      vec2 grid = abs(fract(coord - 0.5) - 0.5) / fwidth(coord);
      float line = min(grid.x, grid.y);

      gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.0 - min(line, 1.0)), 1.0);
    }
`
});

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
scene.add(plane);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  let t = clock.getElapsedTime();
  let scale = 5 + (Math.sin(t) * 0.5 + 0.5) * 2;
  plane.scale.set(scale, scale, 1);
  plane.position.set(
    Math.cos(t),
    Math.sin(t),
    0
  );
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach to go with shaders but I'm afraid it will make adding the numbers of the axis very difficult, at least with my experience with the framework

Comment: @DanielMarques You can make a labelled grid with shaders, it's not that simple though, but it's possible :)